# How to save binary blob from PostgreSQL to file?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Here is my code:

```
    currSrc = connSrc.cursor()
    currSrc.execute("""SELECT request_id, time_beg, shape FROM "REQUESTS" WHERE fl_ready=1""")
```

`shape` have type blob (bytea). I need to save it's on FS. How can I do it with Python?

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted, there should be no difference between PostgreSQL and MySQL blob handling.

Comment: @Erik The answer to that question was a quick fix for a problem caused by a bad design decision which was to save a binary file in a bytea column as a base64 encoded string, not as binary as it should be.

Comment: I strongly recommend against saving files inside the database, since it leads to fast database size growth and consequently to database slowness.

Answer (score 0):

Just write it to the disk:

```
currSrc.execute("""
    SELECT request_id, time_beg, shape
    FROM "REQUESTS"
    WHERE fl_ready=1
""")
rs = cursor.fetchall()
f = open('/path/to/the/file', 'wb')
f.write(rs[0][2])
f.close()
```

The reason for the `[0][2]` is that it is the first line of the result set and the third column.